# How can I access files from an Ext4 partition from a Windows Vista partition on dual-boot setup?

Tags: windows-vista, partitioning, fedora, fedora-12, ext4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a ext4 reader for Windows exist?](https://superuser.com/questions/37512/does-a-ext4-reader-for-windows-exist)

I have a dual-boot setup: Windows Vista + Fedora Linux. Most of my stuff are in the Fedora Linux installation. I want to be able to occasionally access those files from my Windows Vista partition.

Answer (score 2):

[Ext2Read](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/) works swell. It can also open & read disk images ( eg: Wubi disk images)

> Ext2Read is an explorer like utility
>   to explore ext2/ext3/ext4 files. It
>   now supports LVM2 and EXT4 extents. It
>   can be used to view and copy files and
>   folders. It can recursively copy
>   entire folders. It can also be used to
>   view and copy disk and file

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're not using any ext4-specific extensions, you should be able to use [Ext2 IFS](http://www.fs-driver.org/index.html).