# Is there a way to mount an EXT4 volume image in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, mount, ext4, hard-drive-image

Made with ddrescue.

I'm guessing not.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: http://www.ext2fsd.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution, would be to use VMWare to create a virtual machine on W7.
Install your favourite linux OS, then mount the image for it to access, or import as a file then mount.

You could then set up a Samba/CIFS share and access from W7.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did, but with VirtualBox

Comment: Excellent, glad you sorted it.

Answer (score 6):

[Ext2read](http://ext2read.blogspot.com/) allows for read-only viewing, but not actual mounting, nor writing. (via [#37512](https://superuser.com/questions/37512/does-a-ext4-reader-for-windows-exist))

As far as I know there is no driver or application capable of writing to ext4 for Windows.

Comment: Oh nice!  I only need to read from it anyway

Comment: Hmmm.  I don't remember ever using this.  Either it didn't work or I solved the problem in some other way.  Should I accept an answer I've never tested?

Answer (score 5):

If you only need to read from it you can use EXT$ Unpacker, which is free and opensource.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/androidicsjbext/

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for and is WAY better than the accepted answer. Unpack and run - that's it! No hourlong installing of Linux and creating of filesystems in a VM just to view an image ...

Answer (score 3):

**OSFMount**
http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html

> OSFMount allows you to mount local disk image files in Windows with a
>   drive letter.

Works great for mount an Ext4 Image in windows and the download is just 2MB.

About the others:

- **Mount Image Pro v6** [https://dailyuploads.net/ewmo7ypfr1m5]
  (^- could only get it to run by this version with an Anti Dongle patch) 
  BUT 
  Mount Image Pro can't mount Ext4 files (it's just good for *.iso, *.dmg, *.vhd and some more forensic images)
- **FTK Imager 3.4.3** http://ad-exe.s3.amazonaws.com/AccessData_FTK_Imager_3.4.3_x64.exe
  Well I kinda same story - all kinds of CD-image support but none for Ext4

OSFMount doesn't have drop'n'drag support - also the use of *OSFMount.com* is not that simple to easy associate it with *.ext4 or *.img files to mount them.
(it required addition parameters)
So here is a cmd-script 
**OSFMount.cmd**

```
    @prompt -$G

    @echo OSFMount Script 1.0
    @echo ===================
    @echo.

    @set OSFMount_Exe=OSFMount.com
    @set OSFMount_Path="%programFiles%\OSFMount\%OSFMount_Exe%"

    @set MaxDrivesCount=4
    @set MountPoint=#:

    @set options=ro

    @set g_MuteOutput= ^>nul 2^>^&1


    @Call :CheckNSet_PathToExe

    @Call :MayBe_UnMountAll


    ::if "%2" NEQ "" set MountPoint=%2
    @set File=%1
    @set cmd=%OSFMount% -a -t file -m %MountPoint% -f "%File%" -o %options%

    @%cmd%
    @if Errorlevel 1 @(
        @echo Errorlevel: %Errorlevel%
        @call :UnMountAll
        %cmd%
    )


::  %g_MuteOutput% 

::  @pause

@goto :eof

:CheckNSet_PathToExe
    @call :SetIfExist OSFMount %OSFMount_Path%
    @if not defined OSFMount @(

        @call :SetIfExist OSFMount "%~dp0%OSFMount_Exe%"
        @if not defined OSFMount @(

            @echo ERROR: %OSFMount% not found!
            @echo.
            @echo Please copy %~nx0 into same dir where %OSFMount_Exe% is!
            @exit
        )

    )
@goto :eof

:SetIfExist
    @if exist "%~2" set %1="%~2"
@goto :eof




:MayBe_UnMountAll
    :: GetNumberOf (EXT4) Drives
    :: Well OSFMount can also mount other types but this is some kind of compromise or now  
    @set g_CountLines= ^^^| find /c  "="
    @set g_Drives=wmic logicaldisk where FileSystem^^^="EXT4" get Name /value

    @for /f %%x in ('%g_Drives% %g_CountLines%') do @set Lines=%%x

    @echo   Currently mounted drives %Lines% \ %MaxDrivesCount%

    @if %lines% GEQ %MaxDrivesCount% @call :UnMountAll


@goto :eof


:UnMountAll
    @for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%d in (
        '%g_Drives%' 
        ) do @(
    @call :UnMount %%d
    )

    @prompt -$G

@goto :eof

:UnMount

    @%OSFMount% -D -m %1 %g_MuteOutput% 
    @if not errorlevel 1 @echo %1 UnMounted!


    @goto :eof
```

Installation:

1. Copy/paste & save it as OSFMount.cmd (in Notepad or some nicer editor)
2. and put it in the same dir as OSFMount.com. 
   *(Well if OSFMount is installed to "C:\program files\OSFMount" you may also put it somewhere else.)*
3. Create a link to the desktop or the quick launch bar

Usage:

- To mount a image just drag it onto *OSFMount.cmd* (or it's link).
- File association is also as simple - just choose *OSFMount.cmd* in the "open           with" dialog.

Command line example usage:
`OSFMount.cmd d:\android-5.1-rc1\system.img`

Well the next free drive letter is automatically chosen.
If you've mounted more than 4 images the script will reset and unmount the others. (Change the line with MaxDrivesCount=4 in the script if you need more or less. )

So far that script is only made and tested with ext4 images.
To work with other image types like iso's, vhd you may probably modify the script.

Answer (score 0):

Why not? It's just an image.

You can use **FTK IMAGER**, download [here](http://accessdata.com/support/adownloads)

> - A new feature allows users to mount an image as a drive or physical
>     device.
> - FTK Imager 3.0 now provides support for **VXFS, exFAT, and Ext4 file
>     systems**.
> - Safely mount a forensic Image (AFF/DD/RAW/001/E01/S01) as a physical
>     device or logically as a drive letter.

Comment: 1. Most image mounters work on entire drive images, not volumes. 2. Windows doesn't understand EXT3.

Comment: DIY and get a suprise :D

Comment: "Select a valid image file"

Comment: FTK IMAGER does NOT support ext4

Answer (score 0):

You can install [ext2fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) which will install the drivers your Windows machine will need to recognise ext. You an then mount the image with an mounting tool such as Mount Image Pro or FTK Imager.

Comment: The tool you recommend now was already recommended [5 years ago](http://superuser.com/a/246460/493903). What new value does your answer bring?

Comment: There is a difference. Using FTK you can view images, but you cannot mount them due to ext not being supported by Windows. I recommended using ext2fsd to allow FTK/MIP to mount the image as a drive in Windows.

Comment: If you are referring to @Andrew Marshal's answer concerning ext2read, I never noticed it; but my answer still gives a different tool option (ext2fsd).

Comment: ext2fsd only DOES not support the use of image files.
It just works on Ext4 Partitions 
(like \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0 <- hacking in a path to an image file might do the trick; but why ? just use another program like 'OSFMount' )

Comment: Once you have the drivers installed from ext2fsd, you can use a mounting tool to mount an EXT file syste. Both EXT3 and EXT4.