# Access Windows files from Ubuntu

Tags: linux, windows-7, ubuntu, filesystems

I have Windows 7 64bit and Ubuntu 10.04 dual booting on one machine.

I'd like to access my Windows 7 files from within Ubuntu (and preferably vice-versa).  I've not been able to find any tutorials online to tell me how this is done.  There seems to be many tools for Win to Ext2/Ext3 but nothing really providing the solution I need.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you want to mount a hard drive or a partition and create a shortcut to access a file folder. Is it right?

If so, you can read [this post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1886) on ubuntuforums.

[This good tutorial](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/tutoriel/comment_ajouter_un_disque_dur) is in french but is still valuable: to mount permanently a hard drive, you have to edit /etc/fstab to add the windows partition. You should add something like:

```
/dev/hdb1 /media/backup auto defaults,umask=0 0 0
```

at the end of the file.

**/dev/hdb1** is your disk (you can find the proper designation by typing **lshw** in the terminal), **/media/backup** is where you want to mount it.

Answer (score 1):

Opening your Windows files is so easy in Ubuntu and you don't need any tools for that, I think you can find the hard drive under systems.
But to open your linux files from Windows I think you need special tools for that.

Comment: Another problem from Windows is that the Windows tool will have to read all the file systems that Ubuntu supports.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an external harddrive, i simply would open the filesystem browser and click on the harddrive that i want to open - then it magically could open it :-)

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to automatically reach a NTFS from the filesystem browser (if the partition is actually mounted). Just keep going "up" from your home directory (from nautilus) and you'll get there at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu can natively read from and write to NTFS file systems.

Windows can easily read from and write to ext2, ext3, or ext4 file systems by installing a utility outlined in this other [SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/37512/does-a-ext4-reader-for-windows-exist).