# External drive on USB adapter not showing up in Explorer. Anyone have a trouble-shooting path?

Tags: windows-8.1, troubleshooting, usb-storage

I have a USB 2.0 to IDE/SATA adapter and a 1 TB SATA drive. When I plug in the adapter, both the adapter and the drive show up in Device Manager, and Drive Manager shows the drive, but the system will not automatically assign a letter, and I can't assign a drive letter manually.

The drive and adapter work on Linux, but I no longer have Linux on my computer. I currently have Win 8.1, but I've also tried the drive on a Win7 computer. This set-up has previously worked on WinXP.

Anyone got a troubleshooting path to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a Linux file system on it now. Try installing a Linux file system reader. This utility reads most all Linux file systems: http://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/

Run the program and copy off the data to another Windows partition. Now go back into your disk Mgr and delete the partition, create a new one in NTFS, quick format, and assign drive letter. Restore data back to external drive.

Comment: Randy, that was it--thank you. I had thought that I had reformatted it to FAT32 before, but I had not--it's still formatted to ext3/ext4.

Comment: Additional resources for using Linux filesystems in Windows: http://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows .

Comment: @fixer1234  OK, I changed the link.