# KALI data to be recovered

Tags: windows-10, kali-linux

my Kali Linux kde version was corrupted due to gdm3  installation on kde.

I want to recover the files on that partition using windows 10.
please help me on this.
I tried installing nvidia settings and made some changes in xorf.conf file which led the GUI disabled.
now i want to just get my existing files from the partition and re install kali linux.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read ext4 partitions on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Ext4 Partition can be accessed from Windows with
OSFMount
DiskInternals Linux Reader
Paragon ExtFS