# Macrium Reflect: cannot mount ext4 partition from image

Tags: partitioning, ext4, macrium

I created a full disk image of my notebook with Macrium Reflect Free 7.2.4942. Said notebook is configured to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 19.10. Ubuntu is installed in an ext4 partition.

Now I'm trying to mount and access the Ubuntu partition within the Macrium Reflect image, mounting the image on another Windows 10 2004 (latest RTM) PC. Since the ext4 partition is unrecognized by Windows, I followed the guide [Browsing Linux Ext File System Images](https://knowledgebase.macrium.com/display/KNOW72/Browsing+Linux+EXT+File+System+Images): I installed [ext2fsd](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/), rebooted and made sure that the ext2fsd service was started. Still, this doesn't work: when I try to mount the Linux partition with Macrium Reflect, Windows 10 doesn't recognize it and just prompts to format the drive.

Since I urgently need to retrieve some files from the image, I'm currently cloning back the partition from the image I took to another, spare drive: the operation is currently in progress, so the image isn't corrupted. This will probably work, but it's an extremely cumbersome task and I'd really like to just mount the image in Windows as it's supposed to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macrium Reflect can successfully *copy* ext*n* partitions, but cannot mount them. However, there are third-party tools, such as free [ExtToFsd](https://knowledgebase.macrium.com/display/KNOW72/Browsing+Linux+EXT+File+System+Images) and [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/), that *can* mount those partitions. **N.B.** On my Windows 10 v.1909 PC, Ext2Fsd *failed*, but DiskGenius successfully mounted the partition.

- Download and install DiskGenius.
- Open Macrium Reflect and *attempt* to explore the ext4 partition.
- The partition *will be successfully* mounted, but Windows warns the the drive is unformatted and requests to format the partition. **Do not** format the partition... just close the warning and Windows Explorer. [Likely, no damage would be done if formatted, because it is a virtual drive, but I won't test that.]
- Open DiskGenius and view and access that new partition, as below.

[image: Viewing ext4 virtual drive in DiskGenius]