# How to boot a virtual machine from an external HD?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, external-hard-drive, virtualization

I have a host system Windows 10 Pro ([system information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viMNk.png)) and I got an **external HD ([devices and printers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGMUS.png)) with a virtual machine image** of a Linux based server side OS.

**I need to open/boot a virtual machine from the images placed on the external HD on my host device with Windows 10.** For this purpose I downloaded and installed VirtualBox, but I don't know how to open/boot a virtual machine from an image placed on this external HD via this software. I have trouble with this, because one the one hand I am not able to import a virtual appliance, because no external HD is listed ([import virtual appliance dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZlti.png)) and on the other hand I am also not able to view this HD with the Explorer in order to look what is inside like a regular usb flash drive ([devices and drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoljZ.png)).

So my question is how to mount this external HD and to open/boot a virtual machine from it via VirtualBox?

I addition I can mention that there is no restriction to use VirtualBox. That was my first choice to get started.

Edit:
I got this HD with the information that there are two images of an OS of a Linux based server where I can deploy my software for testing purposes. But there are some trouble to mount this external HD ([A SS. of disk management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTmN4.png))

Comment: Are you sure it's a disk with an image, rather than a proper boot disk? Please provide a screenshot of _Disk Management_ (right-click the Start button → _Disk Management_).

Comment: I got this HD with the information that there are two images of an OS of a linux based server where I can deploy my software for testing purposes. I added a SS. of disk management in my question.

Comment: Are you able to assign a drive letter to it through disk management?  No drive letter? No mounting and using a drive in windows.  Also, VirtualBox is just fine.  I have to wonder about the partition type too.. disk manager isn't showing us much.

Comment: I am not able to assign a drive letter to it through disk management. I updated the screen shot of the disk management where you can see that the context menu option for assigning a drive letter is disabled. How I should interpreted this issue? Is the HD defect and/or is Windows the wrong host system?

Comment: ext4 filesystem maybe? Try [these](https://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows).