# Synchronize directories between Windows 10 and Centos 8

Tags: windows, backup, centos

I have a Centos 8 server and frequently have to download files to my Windows notebook, make changes to the files, and then upload them back to the server.
I copy and paste the files to my backup directory to keep it in sync with my server.

Sometimes I don't download the files before changing them because I have an up-to-date copy on my backup. I change hundreds of files everyday and I am tired of the repetitive manual download, upload, copy, and paste operations.

What solutions are available on Windows and Centos 8 to help me keep these files in sync?

> **Note:** Centos 8 is mounted with `EXT4` filesystem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential solution I can think of would be to mount the `EXT4` file system to the Windows OS and then once mounted you could setup a script using [Robocopy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy) or some other sort or scripted logic to copy over the files that changed which you need to sync to the Linux `EXT4` file system.

Similarly but from the Linux Centos 8 operating system side, you could mount an SMB shared folder defined on the Windows OS and then use [Rsync](https://ss64.com/bash/rsync.html) or some other sort of scripted logic (or app) to copy over the files that changed which you need to sync to the Windows file system.

What method(s) and/or tools to use and what any correlated scripted logic may look like is really just a trivial matter but what you are trying to accomplish is most definitely possible from both sides.

---

### Potentially Related Resources

- [How to read ext4 partitions on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows)
- [How to mount remote Windows shares](https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/WindowsShares)
- [Using Rsync to backup a Windows Share](https://serverfault.com/questions/502184/using-rsync-to-backup-a-windows-share)

Comment: Thank you so much my friend, I am glad you could help me!