# How to copy paste files from hard drive having Ubuntu filesystem in Windows without using WSL?

Tags: windows-10, ssd, file-transfer

I have an [SSD](https://amzn.eu/d/4v4t9YY) in which I installed Ubuntu 20.04. But I could no longer use the SSD. More details here: https://askubuntu.com/q/1292824

Now I bought a [SATA to USB A cable](https://amzn.eu/d/hujvMR0). Now, how do I copy paste files from the SSD to my Windows 10 laptop without using WSL?

I would love to use some FOSS to copy paste files from Ubuntu SSD to Windows laptop. Please guide me.

[image]

I want to copy files from Disk 1 and paste them in Disk 0.

Comment: What format is the disk? Are you asking about reading in Windows files from a Linux disk format? Does the disk show up in Disk Management?

Comment: @harrymc I'm not sure about the format of the disk (the format is not mentioned in Disk Management). The disk is shown in Disk Management. I'm using a Windows laptop and I want to access Linux files which are stored in an SSD using Windows laptop. I have added Windows Management screenshot in question.

Comment: [This post](https://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows) might help.