# access files in Manjaro partition from Windows partition

Tags: linux, windows, partition-recovery, manjaro, pacman

I am dual-booting Windows 10 and Manjaro Linux. While running a pacman -Syu on the Manjaro partition, the computer crashed. Pacman stopped working and at first I tried to fix it by deleting the lock file, looking at the mirrors, updating the db lists again. But, after trying to reboot the system it was unable to start back up again. It just dumped me into a terminal that looked like this:

```
[0.599365] Initramfs unpacking failed: read error
mount: error while loading shared libraries: libmount.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
mount: error while loading shared libraries: libmount.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
mount: error while loading shared libraries: libmount.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
mount: error while loading shared libraries: libmount.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/init: line 16: can't open /proc/cmdline: no such file
:: running early hook [udev]
kmod: error while loading shared libraries: libzstd.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
systemd-tmpfiles: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-shared-253.10-1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/init: line 9: /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd: not found
:: running hook [udev]
:: triggering uevents...
udevadm: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-shared-253.10-1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
udevadm: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-shared-253.10-1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
udevadm: error while loading shared libraries: libsystemd-shared-253.10-1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
:: running hook [keymap]
:: loading keymap...done.
ERROR: device '' not found. Skipping fsck.
:: mounting '' on real root
mount: error while loading shared libraries: libmount.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: Failed to mount '' on real root
You are now being dropped into an emergency shell.
sh: can't access tty: job control turned off
[rootfs~]#
```

I cannot type anything into the rootfs emergency shell. Maybe the computer can't connect with the keyboard?
I tried following this guide (https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/pacman#Pacman_crashes_during_an_upgrade) to fix the issue, but I am unable to boot from USB since the USB does not show up in the BIOS menu. Before trying anything more drastic, I wanted to ask if there is any way to grab certain files in the Manjaro partition from my Windows partition. I have homework to do so I need to put off fixing this issue until later, but I have some files I need on the Manjaro partition. Or, if possible, I would really like to copy the contents of my home directory to a flash drive or hard drive, but I am not sure how. Specifically, I have a database of KeePass passwords that I would like to salvage.

Comment: Much much easier to make a virtual machine of one of the systems and then map a folder. I do this routinely.

Comment: @John This is probably the way. The only issue is I need to access the files on the Manjaro partition which are currently unaccessable. Once I have those files I'll probably create a similar setup.

Comment: In a VM you can send files either way.

Comment: Or just use a free Windows tool to access *ext4* such as DiskGenius, EaseUS Partition Master, etc. See https://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read ext4 partitions on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows)